# WooCommerce AJAX Pagination no plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to look into how I could create my own WooCommerce AJAX Pagination function. All the tutorials I've found use a plugin and I would prefer not to. I have created an AJAX Pagination function before for another website but, it's not as simple with WooCommerce as the product posts on the shop page are generated automatically, where as before I had created my own loop for getting the content which I then converted into a JSON object to use in JS.

So my questions are, is it possible to plug this functionality into WooCommerce using the original products loop? Or am I going to have to create a new loop for getting the products, but will this cause issues with loading times as the original WooCommerce loop would still run too?

Here's the php for how I achieved AJAX Pagination before on another website, could I somehow plug the WooCommerce loop into this function?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');

function load_more(){

    $paged = $_POST["page"]+1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'customer_testimonial',
        'posts_per_page'    => 2,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'orderby'           => 'date'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $no_of_posts = $query->found_posts;

    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
            $post_cont[] = array(
                "name"  =>  get_field('customer_name'),
                "area"  =>  get_field('area'),
                "review"    => get_field('review')
            );
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    // echo json_encode($result);
    $max_posts[] = array(
        "no_of_posts"   => $no_of_posts
    );
    echo json_encode(array( "post_cont" => $post_cont, "max_posts" => $max_posts));
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}
```